# Regarding ADO.Net

Tags: database, ado.net

What is the difference between using oledbDataReader and DataAdaptor ?

Which one is best to use ? for fetching data from db...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ADO.NET either in a generic style (using the interface definitions), which makes it easier to port your app to a new database, or in a DB-specific form.

If you're using SQL Server and don't plan to switch, then it's usually better to stick with the `SqlClient` classes, such as `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlDataReader`.

To fetch from a DB, the best option depends in part on where you want to put the data after you read it. `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` is good for `DataSets` or `DataTables`; `SqlDataReader` is good for custom classes. `SqlDataReader` is probably a bit faster, but it also does less for you.

Comment: can u elaborate little bit more on that you mentioned "SqlDataReader is good for custom classes.".

Comment: For example, say that you have a class where you would like to have one instance of the class represent one row from the response to a query. With `SqlDataReader` you can quickly read a row, and then use the results to populate a new instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

I belive there`s some kind of confusion in this question.

DataReader is used for read-only stream of data, while DataAdapters are used to read and write data using DataSets.

Both can be used with OleDB, SQL or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

There are a long list of disadvantages of using DataSets. Unless you have a specific reason for using DataSets (which go hand in hand with DataAdapters), default to using DataReaders.

[Hanselman has a recent good post comparing four types of data access including DataSets and DataReaders](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions.aspx).